# SQL query for simple table

Tags: sql

I have a table:

```
 ( EmployeeID (int), CourseID (int))
```

It is 1 to many relation. Employee can have many courseID.

```
EmployeeID         
   1                  
   1                  
   2                  
   2                  
   3                  
   3                  
   3       

CourseID            
   1                  
   2                  
   2                  
   3                  
   1                  
   2                  
   3
```

for example I would like to know number of employee who has courseID 1 and 2

```
Select  COUNT([employee ID])
From EmployeeTable
Where courseID = 1 and courseID = 2
```

Answer should be 2 because only EmployeeID 1 and EmployeeID 3 has CourseID 1 and 2.

Comment: I would expect it to be many-to-many, not 1-many. A course can be attended by many employees

Comment: Are you asking for two separate numbers, ie. the number of employees in course 1 and the number of employees in course 2, or a single number, ie. the number of employees in *one of* the courses (either course1 or course2)?

Comment: [This](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) can help with demo text table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WHERE clause is evaluated for each row returned by your FROM clause. As you have it, the WHERE clause is checking if Course ID has 2 different values, this will never evaluate to true. A solution I see is using a self join.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmployeeTable AS ET1 JOIN EmployeeTable AS ET2 ON ET1.[employee ID] = ET2.[employeeID] AND ET1.[course 
ID] = 1 AND ET2.[course ID] = 2
```

This looks like a join table. If you had a separate employee table you could do something easier with a subquery.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fast way using `count distinct` to select and count all employees that have both courses 1 and 2

```
select count(*) from (
    select EmployeeID
    from EmployeeTable
    where CourseID in (1,2)
    group by EmployeeID
    having count(distinct CourseID) = 2
) t
```

Comment: I believe this would include employees who are in both course 1 and 3, or in both course 2 and 3.

Comment: @GendoIkari no, the where clause only includes courses 1 and 2

Comment: Right, but it's an "in", so an employee who is in 1, but not 2, would be included.

Answer (score 1):

This is not so simple... your attempt will return 0 because no single row has both CourseID = 1 AND CourseID = 2.

You can do it using subqueries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM EmployeeTable e1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM EmployeeTable e2
    WHERE e2.CourseID = 1
    AND e2.EmployeeID = e1.EmployeeID
)
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM EmployeeTable e3
    WHERE e3.CourseID = 2
    AND e3.EmployeeID = e1.EmployeeID
)
```